# Neo4j MERGE Query

Tags: merge, neo4j

```
MERGE (n : Person { id : 1000) 
MERGE (m : Item   { id : 2000}) 
SET m.name ='xyz' 
MERGE (n)-[r:Buy]->(m)
```

I am trying to upload this kind of data (around 10k+) to Neo4j but the MERGE query is becoming very slow to execute, since for each MERGE it needs a full scan of the node space to verify no other item exists with the given property.

Is there any way to solve this ?

Comment: Do you have constraints or indexes on Person.id and Item.id ?

Comment: I tried CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (person:Person) ASSERT person.id IS UNIQUE CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (item:Item) ASSERT item.id IS UNIQUE but again its slows down as the data grows..


CREATE INDEX ON :Person(id)
CREATE INDEX ON :Item(id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a unique constraint on the `id` properties of the `:Person` and `:Item` nodes, these will become indexed and will then be scanned much more efficiently.

The syntax you'll need will look something like this:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (person:Person) ASSERT person:id IS UNIQUE
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (item:Item) ASSERT item:id IS UNIQUE
```

You can find out more about unique constraints here:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-constraints.html

Comment: I tried                                                                 CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (person:Person) ASSERT person.id IS UNIQUE     CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (item:Item) ASSERT item.id IS UNIQUE also CREATE INDEX ON :Person(id)
CREATE INDEX ON :Item(id) but again its slows down as the data grows..

Comment: What's the spec of the machine on which you're running this? How many nodes are you merging and are you doing them all in a single Cypher statement or across multiple statements?

Comment: We are using a medium EC2 instance, the raw files are in S3 (in JSON format), our python program fetches the records from S3 and writes it into Neo (in EC2) the cipher is - neoBatch.append_cypher("MERGE (n : Person { id : '"+usrId+"' }) MERGE (m : Item { id : '"+lik[0]+"'}) SET m.name ='"+lik[1]+"' SET m.category='"+lik[2]+"' MERGE (n)-[r:Like { name : 'Like' } ]->(m)") 
  neoBatch.submit()

Comment: I would recommend using parameterised Cypher queries instead of manual string substitution. Also, as you are using batches, try to batch 300-400 queries in one batch to send those together.

Comment: for first 4000+ nodes it takes around 10-20 sec then it slows down.. is there any configurations to change?

Comment: It's inevitable that as you increase the amount of data stored, your speed will slow down. In this case, you can probably give your server a boost by increasing the amount of RAM available. Have a look at [tweaking your JVM heap size](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/configuration-jvm.html) - by default this will be a quarter of available system RAM. You could also look at larger AWS instances.

Comment: Thank you Nigel Could you provide me some links on using parameterised Cypher queries... i am using py2neo

Comment: how many transaction can i append before execute using  session.create_transaction() link : http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/cypher/